View the definition of an existing table in PostgreSQL
I tried to get the query of an existing table in PostgreSQL database using DBeaver IDE. Query which was used to create the table and its relationships.
I tried mentioned below 4 queries but those are not working
pg_dump --table metal_products --schema-only

select view_definition from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'metal_products';

select definition from pg_tables where tablename = 'metal_products'

pg_dump -t 'schema-name.metal_products' --schema-only database-name

/+d metal_products

These are not working. How can I do that ?

/ is distinct from \. You need to use a backslash for meta-commands.


That would be \d+ metal_product as shown here psql. 2) If you want schema-only you need to add -s to the commands as shown here pg_dump. 3) Is the table name actually all lower case?  4) There is no view_definition  in information_schema.tables  or definition in pg_table 5) A little bit of time in the docs would have solved your problems.


I got it. In DBeaver IDE perform below steps
Databases --> DatabaseName --> Schemas -->
Public --> Find your table and right click -->
Generate SQL --> DDL

Or
Just double click on table name and then DDL tab

If you double-click on the table, you also have a "DDL" secondary tab under the "Properties" tab.

@ÁlvaroGonzález - that's great. It also works.
